# How to tell in Google Maps if a route ascends or descends?

Tags: google-maps

When you find a walking route on Google Maps, can you tell whether it is climbing up or going down?

Comment: Is there anyway to enable topographic/contour lines? These will give indications of elevations around the walking route. Not sure if there will be though, because the variance at such a small scale map/view will be *extremely* small.

Answer (score 1):

A google search of "Google maps elevation" brings you to

[Google Maps Find Altitude](http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm)

OR

[Google Maps elevation for a route](http://www.doogal.co.uk/RouteElevation.php)

Then you can compare the altitude of the point of a route.

For developers, these websites basically use [The Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/) or [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Reference: google.maps.ElevationService class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#ElevationService).

Answer (score 1):

Another option (which might not work everywhere in the World) is to click on the pedestrian icon:

[image: Walk elevation]

The above shows that from North Downs Way at 161 ft it is 466 feet uphill to 627 ft at Zig Zag Road.

Comment: This is a feature which was added in the last year or so (so much later than when the question was asked). It works for walking and biking routes.